# PHP-FPM issue on LEMP Stack and WordPress

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php-fpm

I'm very much a NGINX and Server Admin beginner.

I used this tutorial to install NGINX / PHP / mySQL / WordPress:

[C3M Digital Tutorial](http://c3mdigital.com/wordpress-performance-server/)

In this tutorial the  backend php-cgi setup is configured using fastcgi.  php5-fpm was installed during this tutorial:

```
apt-get install nginx-full php5-fpm php5 php5-mysql php5-apc php5-mysql php5-xsl php5-xmlrpc php5-sqlite php5-snmp php5-curl
```

After reading that the NGINX configuration on the WordPress codec was more secure than most tutorials, I decided to use the codex configuration:

[WordPress NGINX configuration in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)

The Codex configuration uses php-fpm for backend php-cgi.  When opening the browser I got a 502 Bad Gateway error.  The error log was:

"2012/06/10 21:18:27 [crit] 14009#0: *4 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No 
such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 12.3.456.789, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", hos
t: "mywebsite.com""

In the main NGINX configuration file supplied by the codex I noticed the line starting "server unix:" in the upstream php block which point to the empty directory:

```
    # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
upstream php {
    server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
#       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

I checked the folder at /tmp and it was empty.

Seems I missed configuring php-fpm to play with NGINX.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Is `php-fpm` running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't setup php-fpm to listen on the Unix socket.  I'm guessing your using Debian of some sort, since the instructions you are following are for Debian.

In my Debian/nginx/php config I have this file: `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` You need to edit this to allow php-fpm to listen on the Unix socket as opposed to the 127.0.0.1:9000 address.

Find the line in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` that reads `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and change it to `/tmp/php-fpm.sock` (or comment it out and add the `listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock` below it). Or maybe you want to store the php-fpm.sock file somewhere other than tmp.  Google can probably help you with that.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the noob questions, but I have a couple: 1. what are the differences between the choices (127.0.0.1:9000 and /tmp/php-fpm.sock?) 2. are semicolons used for single line comments?  Thanks.

Comment: @jw60660: 127.0.0.1:9000 uses TCP/IP to connect - it has more overhead, but is helpful in cluster scenarios (where external machines are trying to connect). /tmp/php-fpm.sock is a socket connection - it is faster with less overhead, but can't be used from an external machine. The php-fpm.conf (and associated files) are INI files - so, yes, the semi-colon is a single line comment.